Getting python error about 'iloc' when not using iloc in the code
I am trying to run a python function from matlab, and get the following error when I call it:
Error using <string>><module>
Python Error: AttributeError: 'memoryview' object has no attribute 'iloc'

In the code I am calling there is no (obvious) reference to iloc that I can see.
I am new to python and trying to get code provided by someone else to work
Here is the call function I used in matlab command window:
OptP = pyrunfile("test_curve_fit_python.py", "OptP", CompoAssay=CompoAssay(:,3:5), CompoAssayFG=CompoAssayFG(:,1:3))

And here is the code "test_curve_fit_python.py"
I want the output OptParameter back in my matlab workspace.
Here is the code:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Define Elements
Elts = ['Fe', 'SiO2', 'Al2O3']

# Define Low and and Upper bounds
InitialParameters_Lower = np.array([[-5, -5, 0.1, 50],
                                [-5, -5, 0.1, 0],
                                [-5, 0, 0.1, 0]])

InitialParameters_Upper = np.array([[5, 5, 2, 70],
                                [5, 5, 2, 10],
                                [5, 5, 2, 10]])

# Initialize parameters
OptParameters = np.zeros((len(Elts), 4))

# Define Bias Correction function 
def BiasCorr(x, L, k, x0, T):
    return L / (1 + np.exp(-k * (x - x0))) + T

# Placeholder pour les résultats de l'ajustement
fitresult = {}
gof = {}


def calc_BiasCorr(CompoAssay, CompoAssayFG)
# CompoAssay = p:
# CompoAssayFG = pFG:

for elt_index, elt in enumerate(Elts):
    # Prepare data to fit the  curve
    # Labelt = CompoAssay.iloc[:, elt_index + 2]
    # FGbiaselt = CompoAssayFG.iloc[:, elt_index] - CompoAssay.iloc[:, elt_index + 2]
    Labelt = CompoAssay[:, elt_index]
    FGbiaselt = CompoAssayFG[:, elt_index] - CompoAssay[:, elt_index]

    # Define lower and upper bounds 
    lower_bounds = InitialParameters_Lower[elt_index]
    upper_bounds = InitialParameters_Upper[elt_index]

    # Flag outliers 
    P = np.percentile(FGbiaselt, [5, 95])
    I = (FGbiaselt < P[0]) | (FGbiaselt > P[1])
    outliers = np.where(I)[0]

    # Exclude outliers
    Labelt_filtered = Labelt[~I]
    FGbiaselt_filtered = FGbiaselt[~I]

    # Initial parameters and fit 
    initial_guess = [0.95, 0.96, 0.15, 0.97]
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(BiasCorr, Labelt_filtered, FGbiaselt_filtered, p0=initial_guess, bounds=   (lower_bounds, upper_bounds))

    # Store the  fit results for each element 
    fitresult[elt_index] = popt
    OptParameters[elt_index, :] = popt
return OptParameters

BiasCorr = BiasCorr()
OptP = calc_BiasCorr(CompoAssay, CompoAssayFG)

print(OptParameters)


You've tagged this with matlab but the only link to MATLAB is that's where you're running Python from... do you get the same error if you run the script directly without MATLAB in the middle?

This code isn't valid. The syntax is wrong, and BiasCorr() won't work since it needs arguments. Secondly, this is probably more code than necessary to reproduce the issue. Please make a [mre], and include the full error message with traceback, which I imagine you can get by running the Python file directly. I've never used Matlab, if that's relevant.

@Wolfie I haven't run the script outside of MATLAB because the data is all in MATLAB & the whole point is that I can call it and run it from there.

@wjandrea I am a novice and since I don't appear to be calling iloc I included the whole code in the hope someone could help me understand why I was getting an error to something that wasn't obviously in my code.

A good first step to debug issues is to simplify them as much as possible. A [mcve] benefits us because it means we could run your code and reproduce the issue (we currently can't because we don't have your input data), and helps you to isolate the issue. Your data is in MATLAB, but at the point it calls your Python code it looks like you only need the numbers from two matrices, can you just save that data and then just load it in with Python to run it directly? Then you know if the MATLAB/Python interface is the issue, or not, and you can probably iterate on debugging faster too.
